# how to use users own IP address while parsing a website

Tags: php

i use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get some data from another website. It is a online summary generator tool. Big problem is while my server IP send a hundred requests in a second to source website  and get blocked 
So, how i can use users own IP address while parsing a website?
I know about using a proxy with simple php html dom parser but it's another big problem to me.
Please give me ideas. Thanks
**you may found a duplicate post on phpfreaks forum.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot with server-side coding like PHP. The request needs your IP address, otherwise your server would not get a response!

To send something with the user's IP, it has to be sent from the user's network. That means running in the user's browser. Javascript is the easiest way to do this, although Java, Flash and similar plugins can all do it.

Of course you need the answer on your server, so you need to write code that requests the data from your user's computer and code to send it from the user's computer to your server.

Comment: thanks, do you think that using proxy is a good idea in this case?

Comment: No. You'l need a proxy network otherwise the proxy IP will get banned and you'll be back to square one.